# Нужны ли кавычки и как оформить запись "А-5"?

Tags: пунктуация

Он прекрасно обосновался в секторе А-5. 
Как оформить сочетание "А-5"? Требуются ли кавычки и дефис?

Answer (score 1):

Это не языковой вопрос. Не вопрос грамматики. Как принято, так и надо писать. Кавычки - вряд ли, а вот А5 или А-5 - вопрос решается "по традиции", т.е. как писали раньше, как принято. Нет традиции - пишите, как хотите. Я почти всегда встречал подобные обозначения без дефиса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ... Я понимаю, что когда дело касается формата листов ( А4, А5), то дефис не нужен. Но как быть в случае обозначения территории ( а именно  сектор А 5) - не знаю...

Comment: Видел я и обозначения квадратов территорий. По мне так и там не нужен. Хотя и не ошибка. Повторяю - всё зависит от того, где как принято обозначать.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я так и не поняла точно ставить дефис или нет...

Comment: Ставьте. Или не ставьте. Но везде одинаково. Ошибки не будет в любом случае. Повторяю: это не вопрос грамматики, а вопрос соглашения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93801/discussion-between-behemothus-and-niemand).

Answer (score 1):

***Он прекрасно обосновался в секторе А-5.***

Хорошо выглядит именно такое оформление. Буква А обозначает сектор, цифра 5 обозначает точное место,  дефис - тире разделяет эти ориентиры, добавляя чёткости.

***Кавычки излишни***, А-5 отлично выделяется в тексте и без них.

Answer (score -1):

Кавычки не нужны точно. Они просто ничем не мотивированы, это же не названия типа "Красный Октябрь", а условное обозначение, уникальное по своей сути.

Что касается дефиса... Тут сложнее.
Такие вещи не регулируются правописанием. Спросите у тех, кто вводил подобные обозначения. Если это авторский текст, оставьте как есть. Если это ваше личное обозначение, то никто не вправе вас заставить его изменить.

Вообще хотелось бы ситуативный контекст. Откуда такое свалилось на вашу голову? 
Военные обычно дефисы не ставят в подобных обозначениях. Но тут тоже нет какого-то общего правила...

Comment: Да, дефис - это мое личное обозначение... Но я не знаю, уместен он здесь или нет...

Comment: @NaraMamedova - Если ваше личное, то какие еще вопросы могут быть? Хозяин - барин. Но еще раз прошу объяснить ситуацию в целом. К сожалению, моя попытка выяснить что-то в комментариях не была одобрена модераторами. Так что больше ничего сказать пока не могу.